# optional argument Array.to_i still returns array

Tags: ruby, parameter-passing

I'm creating a simple `repeat(string, number)` function with an optional argument to repeat a string multiple times.  I've had a good look at the forums and tried to use them well - so please forgive me if this has been answered before. When I call the function with a number of repeats the `*arg` creates an array of the integer and I cannot seem to convert that to an integer with .map(&:to.i) or simply array.to_i. Any help is appreciated here :)

This code fails as it tries to evaluate `number < 3`

```
def echo(string)
    string
end

def shout(string)
    echo(string).upcase
end

def repeat(string, *number)
    number = number.map { |i| i.to_i }
     outputStr = ''
    if number < 3
       echo(string) + " " + echo(string)
       #puts number.inspect.length
       else
           #count = number
           while number > 0
           number -= 1
           outputStr += echo(string) + " "
           end
       outputStr[0, outputStr.length - 1]
        #    
        #     number.times do {|i| outputStr += echo(string) + " " + echo(string)}

        #     end
        #     outputStr
    end
end

repeat('hi', 3)
```

Comment: Are you intending to call this as `repeat('hi', 3, 1, 2)` or with some arbitrary series of numbers on the end?

Comment: Also: `([ 'hi' ] * 3).join(' ')` basically does what you want.

Comment: If you are only passing a single number to your method then defining it as `def repeat(string, number)` would be better.

Comment: @tadman Correct, I should have been more specific in that I must follow the arguments as given to me. I really appreciate the other possibilities you've given

Comment: arbitrary singular number is the answer to your first Q. the fn could be called with no second arg at all.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> This code fails as it tries to evaluate `number < 3`

I receive following error when running your code

```
echo_repeat.rb:13:in `repeat': undefined method `<' for [3]:Array (NoMethodError)
Did you mean?  <<
  from echo_repeat.rb:31:in `<main>'
```

You are trying to ask if an array is less than 3 and Ruby does not know to handle that. You could try evaluating the array for if [`one?`](http://ruby-doc.org/core-2.4.0/Enumerable.html#method-i-one-3F), [`any?`](http://ruby-doc.org/core-2.4.0/Enumerable.html#method-i-any-3F) or [`all?`](http://ruby-doc.org/core-2.4.0/Enumerable.html#method-i-all-3F) are less than 3; e.g.

```
number.one? { |n| n < 3 }
number.any? { |n| n < 3 }
number.all? { |n| n < 3 }
```

However, you mentioned that

> I'm creating a simple repeat(string, number) function with an optional argument to repeat a string multiple times.

And your `repeat` function accepts an array of arguments as `number` parameter.

```
def repeat(string, *number)
```

Is this intentional, because in order to declare an optional argument you should set the parameter for when it is not given; e.g.

```
def repeat(string, number = 1)
```

This will only repeat the string once, when no `number` is given; e.g.

```
repeat('hi')
# => "hi"
repeat('hi', 3)
# => "hi hi hi"
```

Comment: I'm blown away by the amount of people helping other people on StackOverflow and i really appreciate the time you took to answer my question. I hadn't found another way to enter an optional argument (number) other than array of arguments ```*number ```  . with your answer I understand how setting the parameter for when ```*number``` is not given is handled. Thanks so much!   In addition, this code would work as well -

Comment: ```    def repeat(string, *number)
        number = number.to_s
        number = number[1].to_i
        outputStr = '' ```